# Existing app needs UIScrollView when using Size Classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout, size-classes

I have an iPad app that is written for Portrait mode; I am trying to add Landscape mode to it using Auto Layout.  Everything appears to work just by changing the Size Classes in XCode, except some of the pages are longer when displayed in Landscape mode.  My thoughts are to just add a UIScrollView to each page that needs it, at the top of the view hierarchy.

Is this the preferred method of solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when designing an app for both landscape and portrait orientations you usually will need to make the content scrollable in landscape orientation.

You can also create a different layout for the landscape orientation and completely re-layout the UI components when the app rotates, but for simplicity putting all of your objects in a scroll view will solve your issue of limited real estate on the screen.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand the procedure: take my existing app, and add a UIScrollVIew to the highest level (_so it is the parent view of all of the subordinate views_).  Do I need any code to determine when I'm in landscape mode, and if so, what for?

Comment: Actually, you will want to embed everything in your view into a UIView, then put that UIView into a UIScrollView.  Setting the content size of the scroll view and using auto layout to fill the space of the screen should automatically decide when the content should be scrollable for you.